# Number of affixes possible

Tags: diablo-iii

I know Legendary items have a fixes set of Affixes but how many affixes are possible for Magic and Rare items?

I estimate that Magic can have 1-3 while Rare can have 3-7? Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rares can have between 4-6 affixes.  It may seem like there can be 7, but some affixes can have multiple effects, such as one providing both a strength and vitality boost.

Blue items can have between 1-2 affixes.  Again, some mods may make it seem like having 3 affixes due to having 2 effects.

Comment: Ah I see. I was wondering how my items were sometimes showing up with 7 affixes while the everyone says the maximum is 6. I totally forgot about multi stat affixes! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how many Magic items can have?

Comment: Magic items have 1-2 (if they are multi-stat affixes it could look like more).  Rare items have 4-6.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey: I believe that some crafted blue items (e.g. [Apprentice Hide Gloves](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/apprentice-hide-gloves)) have three affixes, whilst those that drop only have 1 or 2.